# Excute a method from WPF App in MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I´m trying to execute a method from a WPF app which has been added as reference in my new MVC app , but i get a NullReferenceException in the controller.

```
        private ClientCustomerList GetCustomerList()
        {              
            QTSysGlobal.LogicAssemblyAPI.Production.GetCustomers(ref customerList, 200, out ViewError); //Here Occurs the Exception
            if (ViewError)
            {
                view.Dispatcher.Invoke(QTSysGlobal.ErrorDelegate, null);
                return null;
            }
            return customerList;
        }
        public ActionResult customer()
        {
            return View(GetCustomerList());   
        }
```

Comment: Is GetCustomerList() a static method in your WPF application? If not, you will need a reference of your class from your WPF application that holds the method in your MVC application.

Comment: `customerList` also looks like it could be null. Is it a private/public variable of the current controller class?

Comment: nope not a static , its the same method in WPF just copied and pasted it in MVC with all the references needed of course , customerList is a private variable .

Comment: Have you stepped through debugger to verify `customerList` is instantiated?